# Symfony DomCrawler: get caption inside link

Tags: php, symfony, web-crawler, domcrawler

I'm trying to get the caption inside `<a />` tag.
For example: `<a href="test.php">Nice</a>` will output `Nice`.

I'm using Symfony DomCrawler.

This is what I tried:

```
$crawler = Goutte::request('GET', 'somelink');
$crawler->filter('a')->each(function ($node) use (&$links, &$platforms, &$limit, &$titles, &$startIndex) {
    echo 'HTML: ' .$node->text(); //Shows nothing
    echo '<br />';
    echo 'LINK:' .$node->link()->getUri(); //Shows the link
    echo '<hr />';
});
```

I also tried `$node->html();` but no luck. the caption wont show.

Couldn't find anything about it in the [API](http://api.symfony.com/3.2/Symfony/Component/DomCrawler/Link.html) aswell.

Any ideas?